# Mature and robust open source C library for audio file conversion

Tags: audio, c

I'm looking for mature and robust open source C library for audio file
conversion. It should be C because I really program in Haskell and it's
easier to write bindings for C (unless decent bindings already exist, of
course).

It is desirable that the library could work with:

- AIFF
- FLAC
- MP3
- WAV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) libraries, specifically [libavcodec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec):

- Can decode and encode most common audio & video codecs *as well as several obscure ones* - including those you mention above.
- Open Source & Gratis
- Cross Platform
- Written in C/C99
- Mature & Robust - definitely.
- There are already some Haskell bindings [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ffmpeg-light) and several other places.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I'll look at `libavcodec`'s API. Those bindings kinda thin (most functions directly translate to C), maybe I'll have to write higher-level and more audio-centered ones... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for a high-level method to decode audio files, take a look at [this](https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-audio-file/)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX

Sound eXchange, abbreviated SoX, is a free cross-platform digital audio editor, licensed under the GNU General Public License (libsox is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License), and distributed by Chris Bagwell through SourceForge.net. SoX is written in standard C, and has a command-line interface.

I use it on the command line.